# how to focus recyclerview item inside horizontalscrollview in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, horizontalscrollview

I have vertical Recyclerview inside Horizontal Scrollview when I am in 100th position in recycler view when I use horizontal scroll view that time, Automatically focus is coming to the top of the items from 100th position. How to focus 100th position only even though if they use horizontal scroll view in 100th position.I am sure that items are not recreated.

```
     <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/rv_stockDisposal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        tools:listitem="@layout/list_disposal_species" />
                </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have cleared the edit text focus by adding these properties in recyclerview.then it stopped me taking 100th position to first position.

```
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```